# Does CKY really require CNF?

Tags: nlp, grammar, context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form, cyk

I've read a number of places that the CYK/CKY algorithms require the grammar to be in Chomsky Normal Form (CNF), e.g.

> The standard version of CYK operates only on context-free grammars
>   given in Chomsky normal form (CNF) ~[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm)

However, I've also seen a number of examples of CKY algorithms where the grammar was not in CNF.  A common example that Christopher Manning uses is "fish people fish tanks" (ref: [PPT slide #19](http://nlp.stanford.edu/courses/lsa354/SLoSP-2007-4.ppt)) which contains unary rules:

```
S -> NP VP [0.9]
S -> VP [0.1]
VP -> V NP [0.4]
Vp -> V [0.6]
...
```

I've also seen other examples demonstrating CKY that use three non-terminals in the RHS of the production (e.g. `VP -> Verb NP NP` [reference](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~juliahmr/cs598/Slides/Lecture3.pdf#page=43)).  Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The runtime of CYK depends on the length of the longest production rule, since the algorithm considers all possible ways of decomposing a string into k parts for a production of length k. This means that the runtime per phase is O(n<sup>k</sup>), where k is the length of the longest production. Since there are O(n) phases, the runtime of CYK on a grammar with maximum production length k is O(n<sup>k+1</sup>).

CYK will work correctly on grammars that aren't in CNF, but the runtime may not end up being cubic in the length of the string. The CNF requirement just forces k = 2 and therefore guarantees an O(n<sup>3</sup>) overall runtime.